# Does creating a new Thread have a side effect of flushing the cache?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I want to know whether creating a new thread in Java triggers a cache flush. Suppose I do something like this, in this sequence:

1. A thread runs and sets a variable X.
2. The thread creates a new thread.
3. The new thread accesses X.

My question is this: is the new thread, either at the time it is created or at the time it begins execution, guaranteed to see the update made to X by the old thread in step 1?  I understand that if the old thread changes the value of X in the future, it is not guaranteed that the new thread will see these changes. That's fine. I just want to know whether the new thread will see the right values when it starts without need for explicit synchronization.

When I first decided to look into this topic, I thought a simple google search would immediately reveal the answer, but for some reason, I can't find any result that addresses this question.

Comment: Why rely on such obscure guarantees (if they exist at all) if you can just make the variable in question `volatile`?

Comment: @delnan: there's nothing obscure here. This behaviour is clearly specified in Java language specification.

Comment: Now a more obscure guarantee question might be: "A writes X; B created; C reads X" -- is the behavior of this defined? :-)

Comment: @pst: not sure how B is related. In this case, C is guaranteed to see either default value OR value written by A, but it's not specified which one. (Assuming there were no other writes to X, and that "A writes X" and "C reads X" actions are not synchronized by any other means, e.g. by using volatile).

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný Oops, I guess I messed that up. Assuming that `A` and `C` were initially created and `X` could contain some unknown value :) That is, does the effect of creating *any* thread force a memory barrier across existing threads? (Note that this is *not* guaranteed, as per your fine answer, unless I am missing something important.)

Comment: @pst: in general, without proper synchronization, you have only few guarantees on visible values. One such guarantee is that you will only see values that were actually written by other threads (that includes default value), not some random value. That isn't very helpful though :) But in case of original question, actions 1 and 3 are properly synchronized!

Comment: @pst: there is synchronization when creating a thread and when waiting  for (joining) a thread.

Comment: @ninjalj: in fact, there is synchronization between "starting a thread" (not just creating) and "running code on the this new thread". Joining is not necessary here.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný: yes, I meant there is synchronization when creating a thread (and the code in the new thread), and a different synchronization when joining a thread. Seems I didn't explain it well.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný, this is not correct according to the specification: "one such guarantee is that you will only see values that were actually written by other threads [...], not some random value". Fields that are larger than 32 bits are not updated atomically. This way, if you have a non-volatile `long` or `double` field accessed with data races, one thread writing to it and another thread reading from it, you might actually see something very different from the default value or the value written by the first thread (ie, suppose it writes 0xFF...FF, you might actually see 0x00..FF).

Comment: Anyways, this is to be **strictly correct** according to the specifications. I doubt that any *modern* JVM running on any *modern* OS, specially on 64-bit processors, would show such behaviour!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is.

In java, there is 'happens-before' relation that specifies what memory effects are visible between two actions. If "A happens-before B", then action B is guaranteed to see all changes done by action A.

Starting a thread creates 'happens-before' relation between "thread.start()" call and all code that executes on new thread. New thread is therefore guaranteed to see memory effect of changing variable X on first thread.

For quick overview of happens-before relation, see [Memory Visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) part of java.util.concurrent package overview. In your case, interesting bits are:

- Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.
- A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.

More links if you are curious:

- Java Memory Model is described in [Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html)
- [Java Memory Model FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)
- [Everything else about JMM](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/)

Comment: A nice answer, however, reading through this synopsis makes it unclear to me if this is defined: Threads exist, `A, B, variable X is unknown`. `A writes X; B creates C; C reads X`. Note that `C` was created by `B` and not `A` -- thus there is no happens-before with A and C? (Please note that this is *not* what the original question asks, which this question does answer, just musing! :-)

Comment: @pst: yes, you're right. There is no happens-before between "A writes X" and "C reads X" actions in this case.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný: you mean that there _is_ happens-before between "B creates C" and "C reads X", but not between "A writes X" and any other action in B or C.

Comment: For reference, I checked the specific part of the linked doc that notes the synchronization of Thread.start():  "Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on actions, defined as follows: - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts." [from 17.4.4]